# why server GUI freezing after i clicking on startButton for connecting to server (JavaFX)?

Tags: javafx

Its a traficklight programm. the GUI is a server. on GUI i used a button to start the server but my gui is freezing because  it waiting for clients. The cliens are just recivers. i know that i should use threads but i dont know how. the problem is freezing of GUI.please help me

```
public class Controller {
public TextArea meldingPlass;

private static int portNr = 5555;

public void startServer() throws IOException {
    Server cs = new Server();
    cs.connectToServer(portNr);

}
```

}

//Here my SeverThreads class

public class ServerThread extends Thread {

```
Socket s;
InetAddress ca;


public ServerThread(Socket s)
{
    this.s=s;
    ca=s.getInetAddress();
}

public void run()
{
    try(
            PrintWriter out=new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(),true);
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            )
    {
        while (true){
            System.out.println(ca.getHostAddress());
            out.println("Status of Server");
        }
      //  s.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }


}
```

}

//here is ServerClass
public class Server implements Runnable {

```
public  void connectToServer(int portNr){
    try(
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portNr);
    )
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("In Server - while loop");
           ServerThread st = new ServerThread(ss.accept());
            System.out.println("Client connected. Starting client");
            st.start();

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception occurred when trying to listen on port "
                +portNr+ " or listening for a connection");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You don't show all the required code. Most probably you're running your server on the JavaFX thread.

Anyway, here's an excellent resource about [how to create a web server](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/index.html).